# C++ will not run on my mac, symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, c, macos, c++11, eclipse-luna

Heres the code, extremely basic Cpp

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout << "C++ is FUN!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

The symbols that can not be found are "std" trying to use the name space, and "cout".
the full error message is.

```
make: *** [FirstProject] Error 1    FirstProject            C/C++ Problem   
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved FirstProgram.cpp    /FirstProject   line 5  Semantic Error    
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved  FirstProgram.cpp    /FirstProject   line 2  Semantic Error    
symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 FirstProject            C/C++ Problem
```

EDIT:
here is the whole linker line:

```
make all 
Building target: FirstProject
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++  -o "FirstProject"  ./FirstProgram.o   
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [FirstProject] Error 1
```

Does anyone know what could potentially be the problem?

Comment: What compiler/IDE/environment are you using?

Comment: Show the whole compiler line being run by `make`.

Comment: MacOSX GCC in Eclipse Luna

Comment: I added the console line to the post, and it is GCC, G++ isn't an option for me to choose in Eclipse

Comment: That is the linker line from `make`, not the compiler line.

Comment: `Invoking: Cross G++ Linker   g++  -o "FirstProject" ./FirstProgram.o`...

Comment: @trojanfoe I don't know how to find the compiler line, or how to tell eclipse to compile in the answer below

Comment: Probably doing a clean and rebuilding.

Comment: @user3570569, google that error and you will find solutions to overcome that error

Comment: If you are just starting C++ on OSX I would use Xcode as this should just work and only when you learn what the parts of a program are then use other IDEs - and note on recent OSX versions GNU compiler is not there by default it has clang

Answer (score 0):

You are not compiling using a C++ compiler.

If you are using the GNU toolchain then use `g++` and not `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile then link:

```
g++ -c -o FirstProgram.o FirstProgram.c
g++ -o FirstProject FirstProgram.o
```

Or you can combine into one statement:

```
g++ -o FirstProject FirstProgram.c
```